# segmentation fault using stl_tree

Tags: c++, tree, stl

I was trying to use bits/stl_tree.h as a container for my customized type, as following

```
#include <bits/stl_tree.h>

struct my_type {
    double key;
    uint64_t data;
    my_type(double _key, uint64_t _data) : key(_key), data(_data) {}
    my_type(const my_type&) = delete;
};

struct key_of_value {
    constexpr double operator()(const my_type* p) const noexcept {
        return p->key;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::_Rb_tree<double, my_type*, key_of_value, std::less<double> > my_tree;
    auto e0 = new my_type(100.0, 100);
    auto e1 = new my_type(101.0, 101);
    
    my_tree._M_insert_equal(e0);
    my_tree._M_insert_equal(e1);
}
```

I would like to store pointer to the obj inside the tree, since the lifecycle of the obj will be managed by other dude. However on my machine CentOS 8 with GCC 8.3.1, the first insert was ok, and I can see the size of the tree changed to 1, also I can verify the pointer been inserted is valid, the second insert always causes segmentation fault at the comparison part(compare both keys). I wonder whether there is anything missed here.

Comment: Double value as the key? During comparisons the double's precision seem to be problematic. Not sure though.

Comment: `bits/stl_tree.h` -- Why are you using internal compiler headers?  [Read the comments at the top of the file](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_tree.h) -- `Do not attempt to use it directly.`

Comment: @kiner_shah good point, but I dont need a way to tell whether two keys are equal so I think it is ok to use, but I will try switch to int as key

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I need a container that supports binary search and I dont want to use vector inside a std::map for key collision, hence I try to use the data structure underneath std::map

Comment: I also need a way to iterate thru the container to get a ordered sequence, hence std::set is out.

Comment: @cynric4sure: `std::set` is iterable to get an ordered sequence. Do you mean that you want to allow duplicates? In that case you want `std::multiset`

Comment: @AndyG yeah, looks like std::multiset is just what I want, Thanks! But I am still curious what I did wrong about the Rb_tree.

Comment: @cynric4sure *But I am still curious what I did wrong about the Rb_tree* -- What you did wrong was rely on an internal compiler header.  You don't know what important pieces may be missing, what other functions need to be called, etc. for that header to work.  That's why it's internal and not to be used.  It even says clear as ever not to use it -- so what did you expect to happen when you broke the contract?